# Licia of Lindeldt has disappeared

Tags: dark-souls-2

I talked to Licia at the Tower of Flames. Then I returned to Majula and went down the stairs, but she's not there or at the tower. Where is she?

Comment: How far down the stairs did you go? She should be at the contraption. Did you go the whole way from Majula to the first bonfire in the area "Heide's Tower of Flames" and did not encounter her?

Comment: thank you, when I physically walked from majula to the tower of flames, she was there praying. I made sure to exhaust her dialogue, then left. she is now at the contraption! much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only places where you can find Licia of Lindeldt are in Heide's Tower of Flames or in the way between Heide's Tower of Flame and Majula, the only way known for her not to be there is after she's killed (Either you invade her with the Crushed Eye Orb or simply kill her). After she's killed a tombstone MIGHT appear, as far as I know there are certain faith requirements for the tombstone to appear (in the same place where she was standing between Majula and Heide's Tower.

A link to the complete information [here](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Licia+of+Lindelt#.U16qA_l5NZs).